# mysql Database creation with dot

Tags: mysql, database, shell, command

I want to create a database using following syntax

```
mysql -u<uname> -p<password> -e "create database <name>"
```

but whenever I try to use dot (.) in database name, it giving me error.

```
[root@aee9a1889c3f wpg.master]# mysql -uroot -proot -e "create database 'a.n'"
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''a.n'' at line 1

[root@aee9a1889c3f wpg.master]#

[root@aee9a1889c3f wpg.master]#

[root@aee9a1889c3f wpg.master]# mysql -uroot -proot -e "create database `a.n`"
bash: a.n: command not found
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

I know I can do that using sql editor like SQL pro or using mysql command editor, but I want to do that this way. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the `mysqladmin` utility it can be done:

```
mysqladmin -u<uname> -p<password> create a.n
```

If you want to do it using mysql client you need to use single quotes (to avoid shell expansion of the backticks (`)

```
mysql -u<uname> -p<password> 'create database `a.n`'
```

Comment: yup that , I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: I just edited my answer to show how to do it with `mysql` instead of `mysqladmin`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a dot in a database name.

The following documentation lists the permitted characters: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

**From the documentation:**

"database, ... are known as identifiers"

---

*Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:*

- ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)
- Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF

*Permitted characters in quoted identifiers include the full Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), except U+0000:*

- ASCII: U+0001 .. U+007F
- Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF

**Update:**

As mentioned in the documentation, it is possible with backquotes:

```
create database `a.b`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: ASCII: U+0001 .. U+007F does include the `.` symbol (U+002E). So it can be used in quoted identifiers

Comment: yes, we can have try to do from mysql command editor

"create database `a.b`";

Comment: @user6457056 I updated the answer to show a solution with backquotes